# Terminating application from 2nd Form does not stop the debug

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a program that uses multiple forms and I want to be able to terminate the application from form 2 so that its no longer running or debugging.

This is the code that I have tried:

```
 private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 frm = new Form1();
            frm.Close();
            this.Close();
        }
```

Using the above code closes the forms but does not stop the debug process and I'm not sure if this is an issue!

Comment: Is Form1 the Main Form that comes up that Form2 is launched from?  And the toolstrip menu click you show is in Form2?

Comment: spot on son you getting the hang of it :)

Comment: In your example Form1 will not close because you aren't calling Close on a reference to it, you are calling close on a new instance of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to close the entire application you may call [`Application.Exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894.aspx).

Comment: cant believe I didn't try that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code is not working is that you are creating a new separate instance of Form1, not the instance from which Form 2 was launched.

So, you are creating a new instance of Form1, then close the new Form1, then close Form2. While never referencing the instance of Form1 from which Form2 was opened.

If you want Form2 to close the original Form1, then you will need to pass into Form2 a reference to Form1 so that Form2 can call the Close() on the parent instance of Form1.

wRar has the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do Application.Exit as wRAR suggests, or try the following alternative.

In the example given:

```
private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 frm = new Form1();
    frm.Close();
    this.Close();
}
```

Form1 will not close because you aren't calling Close on a reference to it, you are calling close on a new instance of it.

Instead if you didn't want to use Application.Exit, you could always do the following, **assuming you called Form2.Show(this) with a reference to Form1:**

```
private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    this.Close();
}

private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   if ( this.Owner != null )
     this.Owner.Close();
}
```